# "A long time ago, our world lay in turmoil." Is this correct?

Tags: phrase-usage, lie-lay-lain-laid

> “A long time ago, our world *lay* in turmoil.”

Is this correct?

I googled the usage of "lay" in that application, but didn't feel confident in the results. Is this acceptable?

Comment: Yes, it is correct. The past form of "lie" (recline) is "lay".

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was after. I google "world lay in turmoil" but it showed too few results. I'm gonna go with "was".

Comment: @CowperKettle This is not "lie" (recline) but rather "lie" (remain). The world did not put up it's feet and relax. It is more akin to lying in wait. Either way, you are correct.

Comment: @Lacklub Oh, thanks! I had received a comment saying it was not idiomatic and no one would understand, but it's been deleted now. So it is correct, but can you tell me if it's awkward? Does it sound weird to native ears?

Comment: It's fine and natural. (I'm a native speaker of American English.) To me, *lay* is better than *was* because *to be* is not an 'action verb' and has no life. Although there is not a lot of action involved with *lie/lay* it's still an 'action verb'. And something that's 'lying in rest' has the potential to rouse itself to other action.

Answer (score 1):

Your sentence

> A long time ago, our world lay in turmoil.
>   *a long time ago, our world was in a state of turmoil*

is correct.

The use of

> lay

has the meaning of "lying around", if you are lying around, it is your base or usual state.

> He fell alseep as he *lay* there.
>   *he was lying down and fell asleep*

Answer (score -2):

I find the combination of lay and turmoil to be in contradiction. Lay implies little or no movement while turmoil is frenetic and uncoordinated movement.